# Is there a way to make macros for building this kind of table?

Tags: macros, multirow, rowcolor, cellcolor, hhline

Is there a way to make macros that makes a table like this where the colors changes according to the different cells, even though the first couple of cells are a multirow cell. I need to make 16 of these tables with different amount of columns, cells etc. and it seems like a huge amount of work that could be automated a bit. I just really can't seem to find out how.

[image: Table made using the severely impractical method shown below below]

The code written to produce the table are here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%===================================

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,longtable,x11names]{xcolor}                % Definer farver med \definecolor. Se mere: 
\usepackage{multirow} % Fletning af raekker og kolonner (\multicolumn og 
\multirow) 
\usepackage{hhline} % more options for lines between rows and columns
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % New column type P with centering

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{ a4paper, total={180mm,257mm}, left=15mm, top=60mm, bottom=0mm, textheight=180mm, footskip=10mm, headheight=52pt, }

% ====================== HARDWARE ARKITEKTUR ====================================
\begin{document}
\section{HARDWARE ARKITEKTUR} 


\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}[c]{|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|P{3.5cm}|P{3.5cm}|}
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|--}
    \rowcolor{NavyBlue}\textcolor{White}{\textbf{Blok-navn}} & \textcolor{White}{\textbf{Funktionsbeskrivelse}}  & \textcolor{White}{\textbf{Signaler [Porte]} }& \textcolor{White}{\textbf{Kommentar}} \\


\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} Force[userChoice]  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} Brugerens input\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} SVDC [vcc]         & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} Spændingsforsyning\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} Light [display]        & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} Viser brugerens muligheder/valg\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}I2C [gameStatus]    & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}Kommunikation mellem CPU'er\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} \multirow[t]{-7.5}{\hsize}{Score system} & 
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} \multirow[t]{-7.5}{\hsize}{Indeholder brugergrænsefladen som blandt andet er et tegn for en and i en båd med et kosteskaft og en trillebør} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} WIFI [wifi] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} Forbindelse til Database\\


\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|--}


    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}  &  \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}5VDC [vcc] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}Spændingsforsyning\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--} 
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} 12VDC [powerRail] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} Spændingsforsyning\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} IR [dryerSensor] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} IR modtager\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} IR [cupSensor] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} IR modtager\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} IR [dryerLED] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} IR modtager\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} IR [cupLED] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35}IR modtager\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} Light [target] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}Visuelt lys fra kopperne\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} Airflow [airflow] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35}Luft til at tørre bolden\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} \multirow[t]{-10.5}{\hsize}{Cup Zone} & 
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} \multirow[t]{-10.5}{\hsize}{ Sørger for detektering af kopper og bolde i kopperne, og aktivering af motoren i Ball Dryer. Desuden styres belysning under kopperne også her.} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} I2C [gameStatus] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}Kommunikation mellem blokkene\\


\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|--}


    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35}5VDC [vcc] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35}Spændingsforsyning\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}12VDC [powerRail] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}Spændingsforsyning\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--} 
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} Sound [audio] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} Musik der analyseres\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} Light [matrixLight] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} Bordplade lysmønster\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} Light [bgLight] &\cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} Bordplade baggrundsbelysning\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!35}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} \multirow[t]{-7.5}{\hsize}{Light Panel} & 
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} \multirow[t]{-7.5}{\hsize}{Her styres den grafiske belysning på bordet. Belysningen består af en matrix og baggrundsbelysning.} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} I2C [gameStatus] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} Kommunikation bellem blokkene\\


\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|--}


    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15}  & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} 5VDC [vcc] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!35} Spændingsforsyning\\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{NavyBlue!15}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--}
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} \multirow[t]{-2}{\hsize}{Power Supply} & 
    \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} \multirow[t]{-2}{\hsize}{Forsyner systemet med strøm} & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} 12VDC [powerRail] & \cellcolor{NavyBlue!15} Spændingsforsyning\\


\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|--}
\end{tabular} 

\caption{Blokbeskrivelse APP}
\label{Blokbeskrivelse APP}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Finally there is a working example at this URL: [ShareLatex working example](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59f4bcc58ade204b7f11b24c)

Comment: There should be a way to “program” the colors so that you don't need to explicitly say which one for each cell, but I don't know the packages. At the very least you could aim to have `\singlerow{Score system}{Indeholder …}{Force [userChoice], SVDC [vcc], …}{Brugerens input, Spændingsforsyning, …}`. It would be nice if someone that knows how to do this in ConTeXt posted an answer as an informative solution, by the way.

Comment: If you use `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` you can call the command `\rowcolors{<starting row>}{<color1>}{<color2>}` which colours the rows of a table in alternating colours. Then you can use the command `\cellcolor` in the `\multirow` cells to set their colour explicitly. And for the first row you use `\rowcolor{<color>}`

Comment: You say that you need to make "16 of these tables with different amount of columns, cells etc. " Can you give some indication of what the input parameters are? It is hard to automate a process without knowing what the parameters are.

Comment: The different tables are of the following setup:
4 columns, first row title
1 row, 1 row, 5 rows, 5 rows,
1 row, 1 row, 9 rows, 9 rows,
1 row, 1 row, 6 rows, 6 rows,
1 row, 1 row, 2 rows, 2 rows.

The columns of the left side, the 1's, need to switch color according to each other, and the columns on the right side need to switch according to each other, without affecting the other ones.
Just like shown on the example.
Another table could be:
6 columns, 
title row,
1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,3,1,
1,1,1,1,2,1,
1,1,1,4,4,1,
and so on. So there is different amounts of rows per column.

Comment: On this table there the colors needs to follow like above, where one half is colored according to that half's columns and the other half is colored according to the other half's columns.
So it is either 4 or 6 columns

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using the new [tabularray](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. The package allows the seperation of format and content, which makes the code a lot cleaner.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,longtable,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{ a4paper, total={180mm,257mm}, left=15mm, top=60mm, bottom=0mm, textheight=180mm, footskip=10mm, headheight=52pt, }

\begin{document}

\NewColumnType{P}[1]{Q[c,wd=#1]}

\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec = {|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|P{3.5cm}|P{3.5cm}|},
            row{even} = {NavyBlue!35}, row{odd} = {NavyBlue!15},
            row{1} = {bg=NavyBlue, fg=white, font=\bfseries},
            hlines,
        }
        Blok-navn & Funktionsbeskrivelse & Signaler [Porte] & Kommentar \\
        \SetCell[r=5]{h, NavyBlue!35} Score system & \SetCell[r=5]{h, NavyBlue!35} Indeholder brugergrænsefladen som blandt andet er et tegn for en and i en båd med et kosteskaft og en trillebør & Force[userChoice] & Brugerens input \\
        && SVDC [vcc] & Spændingsforsyning \\
        && Light [display] & Viser brugerens muligheder/valg \\
        && I2C [gameStatus] & Kommunikation mellem CPU'er \\
        && WIFI [wifi] & Forbindelse til Database \\
        % next block
        \SetCell[r=9]{h, NavyBlue!15} Cup Zone & \SetCell[r=9]{h, NavyBlue!15} Sørger for detektering af kopper og bolde i kopperne, og aktivering af motoren i Ball Dryer. Desuden styres belysning under kopperne også her. & 5VDC [vcc] & Spændingsforsyning \\
        && 12VDC [powerRail] & Spændingsforsyning \\
        && IR [dryerSensor] & IR modtager \\
        && IR [cupSensor] & IR modtager \\
        && IR [dryerLED] & IR modtager \\
        && IR [cupLED] & IR modtager \\
        && Light [target] & Visuelt lys fra kopperne \\
        && Airflow [airflow] & Luft til at tørre bolden \\
        && I2C [gameStatus] & Kommunikation mellem blokkene \\
        % next block
        \SetCell[r=6]{h, NavyBlue!35} Light Panel & \SetCell[r=6]{h, NavyBlue!35} Her styres den grafiske belysning på bordet. Belysningen består af en matrix og baggrundsbelysning. & 5VDC [vcc] & pændingsforsyning \\
        && 12VDC [powerRail] & Spændingsforsyning \\
        && Sound [audio] & Musik der analyseres \\
        && Light [matrixLight] & Bordplade lysmønster \\
        && Light [bgLight] & Bordplade baggrundsbelysning \\
        && I2C [gameStatus] & Kommunikation bellem blokkene \\
        % next block
        \SetCell[r=2]{h, NavyBlue!15} Power Supply & \SetCell[r=2]{h, NavyBlue!15} Forsyner systemet med strøm & 5VDC [vcc] & Spændingsforsyning \\
        && 12VDC [powerRail] & Spændingsforsyning \\
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{Blokbeskrivelse APP}
    \label{Blokbeskrivelse APP}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image: output]

You can specify the color formatting for odd and even rows in the argument of `tblr` and also add the different formatting for the header. With the command `\SetCell` you can create cells which span multiple rows (simular to multirow). Since your blocks are not always the same size, you have the specify the number of rows and the color specifically.

I don't quite understand your hline commands, so I have just added the option `hlines` to `tblr` which creates black hlines where needed. You can also customize this, see the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) further information.

Since you said that you have many of these tables, it makes sense to define a new environment based on this style.

```
\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr}
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{
    row{even} = {NavyBlue!35}, row{odd} = {NavyBlue!15},
    row{1} = {bg=NavyBlue, fg=white, font=\bfseries},
    hlines,
}

\begin{mytblr}{|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|P{3.5cm}|P{3.5cm}|}
   % content
\end{mytblr}
```